# How to filter products using 2 or more category filters in Magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento

I am looking to get filters of products from two or more categories.

My Category structure is:

**CatA => Product1, Product2, Product3**

**CatB => Product1, Product4, Product5**

I want to get products from **CatA** and **CatB** with **AND** condition. In this ex. result should be **Product1**.

I already follow http://vibrantdrive.com/how-to-filter-magento-products-using-2-or-more-category-filters/. but didn't get any solution. I am usign Magento 1.9.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this code. Now products are filter by multiple categories, but the pagination pages gives same products that are listed in first page.

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
    ->addCategoryFilter(Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(86))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id',array('finset'=>88))
    ->setPage(0, 5)
    ->setOrder('position', 'ASC')
    ;
$_productCollection->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can filter product by category in following way :**

```
$categoryIds = array(2,4);//category id

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                             ->getCollection()
                             ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
                             ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                             ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $categoryIds))
```

Comment: Its showing error: 
Item (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product) with the same id "4" already exist

Comment: user your categoryIds which you want to filter instead of 2,4

Comment: `$categoryIds = array(88,15);

    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                             ->getCollection()
                             ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
                             ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                             ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $categoryIds));`